# Gaufrette (with AWS) & Symfony 4 - Read a picture

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-s3, gaufrette

Good afternoon,

I try to display an image from *AWS S3* storage. I use the gaufrette file configuration which works when I upload file in *AWS S3* storage.

Gaufrette configuration:

```yaml
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        images:
            aws_s3:
                service_id: "infra.aws_s3.client"
                bucket_name: "%amazon_s3.bucket_name%"
                detect_content_type: true
                options:
                    directory: "%amazon_s3.directories.images%"
                    acl: public-read
        documents:
            aws_s3:
                service_id: "infra.aws_s3.client"
                bucket_name: "%amazon_s3.bucket_name%"
                detect_content_type: true
                options:
                    directory: "%amazon_s3.directories.documents%"
                    acl: public-read
        imports:
            aws_s3:
                service_id: "infra.aws_s3.client"
                bucket_name: "%amazon_s3.bucket_name%"
                detect_content_type: true
                options:
                    directory: "%amazon_s3.directories.imports%"
                    acl: public-read
    filesystems:
        images:
            adapter: images
            alias: images_filesystem
        documents:
            adapter: documents
            alias: documents_filesystem
        imports:
            adapter: imports
            alias: imports_filesystem
```

Controller code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Application\Controller;

use App\Application\Controller\Rest\RestController;
use App\Domain\Entity\BuildingMedia;
use App\Domain\Entity\PropertyPicture;
use App\Infrastructure\Command\Command\CommandBus;
use App\Infrastructure\Repository\BuildingMediaRepository;
use App\Infrastructure\Repository\PropertyPictureRepository;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use Gaufrette\StreamWrapper;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Operation;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class MediaController extends RestController
{
    /**
     * @var PropertyPictureRepository
     */
    private $propertyPictureRepository;

    /**
     * @var BuildingMediaRepository
     */
    private $buildingMediaRepository;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $awsS3;

    /**
     * MediaController constructor.
     *
     * @param PropertyPictureRepository $propertyPictureRepository
     * @param BuildingMediaRepository   $buildingMediaRepository
     * @param Filesystem                $awsS3
     * @param SerializerInterface       $serializer
     * @param CommandBus                $commandBus
     */
    public function __construct(
        PropertyPictureRepository $propertyPictureRepository,
        BuildingMediaRepository $buildingMediaRepository,
        Filesystem $awsS3,
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        CommandBus $commandBus
    ) {
        $this->propertyPictureRepository = $propertyPictureRepository;
        $this->buildingMediaRepository = $buildingMediaRepository;
        $this->awsS3 = $awsS3;

        parent::__construct($serializer, $commandBus);
    }

    /**
     * @Operation(
     *     tags={"Media"},
     *     summary="Read a property's picture.",
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="OK"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="400",
     *         description="Bad request"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="401",
     *         description="Unauthorized"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="403",
     *         description="Access denied"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="404",
     *         description="Entity not found"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="500",
     *         description="Internal server error"
     *     )
     * )
     *
     * @ParamConverter("propertyPicture", converter="property_picture")
     *
     * @param PropertyPicture $propertyPicture
     *
     * @return BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function propertyPictureReadAction(PropertyPicture $propertyPicture): BinaryFileResponse
    {
        $adapter = $this->awsS3->getAdapter();

        $filePath = $adapter->read(
            'group'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $this->getUser()->getGroupId().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            'property'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $propertyPicture->getProperty()->getIdValue().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $propertyPicture->getFilename()
        );

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        $response->setContentDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
            $propertyPicture->getFilename()
        );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

If I try to use `getLink()` from `$propertyPicture` (the method returns the file URL save in database), `BinaryFileResponse` not found the file from given URL.

I need to have the file URL from Gaufrette to display the file in API response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try many possible solution, I have find this one for pictures (and it is working perfecly, even if you use a private bucket in *AWS S3*):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Application\Controller;

use App\Application\Controller\Rest\RestController;
use App\Domain\Entity\BuildingMedia;
use App\Domain\Entity\PropertyPicture;
use App\Infrastructure\Command\Command\CommandBus;
use App\Infrastructure\Repository\BuildingMediaRepository;
use App\Infrastructure\Repository\PropertyPictureRepository;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Operation;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class MediaController extends RestController
{
    /**
     * @var PropertyPictureRepository
     */
    private $propertyPictureRepository;

    /**
     * @var BuildingMediaRepository
     */
    private $buildingMediaRepository;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $awsS3;

    /**
     * MediaController constructor.
     *
     * @param PropertyPictureRepository $propertyPictureRepository
     * @param BuildingMediaRepository   $buildingMediaRepository
     * @param Filesystem                $awsS3
     * @param SerializerInterface       $serializer
     * @param CommandBus                $commandBus
     */
    public function __construct(
        PropertyPictureRepository $propertyPictureRepository,
        BuildingMediaRepository $buildingMediaRepository,
        Filesystem $awsS3,
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        CommandBus $commandBus
    ) {
        $this->propertyPictureRepository = $propertyPictureRepository;
        $this->buildingMediaRepository = $buildingMediaRepository;
        $this->awsS3 = $awsS3;

        parent::__construct($serializer, $commandBus);
    }

    /**
     * @Operation(
     *     tags={"Media"},
     *     summary="Read a property's picture.",
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="OK"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="400",
     *         description="Bad request"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="401",
     *         description="Unauthorized"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="403",
     *         description="Access denied"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="404",
     *         description="Entity not found"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="500",
     *         description="Internal server error"
     *     )
     * )
     *
     * @ParamConverter("propertyPicture", converter="property_picture")
     *
     * @param PropertyPicture $propertyPicture
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function propertyPictureReadAction(PropertyPicture $propertyPicture): Response
    {
        $adapter = $this->awsS3->getAdapter();

        $content = $adapter->read(
            'group'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $this->getUser()->getGroupId().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            'property'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $propertyPicture->getProperty()->getIdValue().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
            $propertyPicture->getFilename()
        );

        return new Response($content, 200, array(
                'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'
        ));
    }
}
```

The `read()` method from `Gaufrette` returns the file content, not the real path. So, I have just change the returns value from `BinaryFileResponse` to `Response` and set manually the `Content-Type`.

The next upgrade, if you have the same processing is to set the type MIME in database when file is save and returns it when you need to display it like with a similar route from your API.